# NextJs 14 + Zustand

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, app-router, zustand

https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand/guides/nextjs

This documentation explains how to use Zustand with NextJS.

I did not understand fully the document and the use of React Context was needed there.

Also for cases where I want to initialize my store with data I am fetching from the server, how would that look like? Would I populate the zustand store in a useEffect?

Problem is I can't find anyone who is using the same approach as the one documented.